# Is Google Scribe still available on blogger.com?

Tags: blogger, google-scribe

In 2011, Google Scribe was discontinued as a standalone website, and [added as a feature to Blogger.com](http://bloggerindraft.blogspot.com/2011/08/introducing-google-scribe-in-blogger.html), but now I can't find it anywhere on the website (since the user interface has changed since then). Is the Google Scribe feature still available on Blogger, or has it been temporarily removed?

Comment: I used to use Google Scribe as a creative writing/brainstorming tool (before it was discontinued as a standalone product), and I still haven't found an adequate replacement for it. :/

Answer (score 1):

That announcement you've linked to says it was available in [Blogger-in-draft](http://www.draft.blogger.com), but I don't believe it ever made it through to "production" ie [www.blogger.com](http://www.blogger.com).

Blogger-in-draft is like a beta version of blogger:  sometimes new features usually get released there first, but sometimes they aren't quite right yet, and sometimes Google are just testing whether a feature is worth it or not.

Comment: The correct link to the "draft" version of Blogger is here: http://draft.blogger.com/home The feature was introduced to draft.blogger.com, but it's apparently gone now.